# Links in bootstrap 4.3.1 dropdown don't work

Tags: bootstrap-4, dropdown

- I have vanilla Bootstrap 4.1.3 dropdown from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/

  - I have the bootstrap css , js bundle & jquery from cdn
  - The dropdown works fine
  - The links to id='#xxx' in section tag don't work
  - This question looks similar and it doesn't appear to have gotten an answer that worked - [Bootstrap navbar dropdown link does not work when bootstrap.min.js is in the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083477/bootstrap-navbar-dropdown-link-does-not-work-when-bootstrap-min-js-is-in-the-cod?newreg=e86d93cb430a4240b56fa99ab95666d9)

```html
<div class="dropdown">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> <!-- Put in hamburger -->
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#about">About Me</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#heritage">My Heritage</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Expect to see selected pages; no error messages

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it work fine... example:

```css
article {margin-top: 100vh; width: 90%; border: 5px solid black;} /* just for the demo */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">hamburger</span> <!-- Put in hamburger -->
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#about">About Me</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#heritage">My Heritage</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
  </div>
</div>

<article id="about">ABOUT</article>
<article id="heritage">hERITAGE</article>
<article id="contact">CONTACT</article>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Edit - using bootstrap 4.3.1 with same result (ie - working as expected):

```css
article {margin-top: 100vh; width: 90%; border: 5px solid black;} /* just for the demo */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">hamburger</span> <!-- Put in hamburger -->
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#about">About Me</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#heritage">My Heritage</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
  </div>
</div>

<article id="about">ABOUT</article>
<article id="heritage">hERITAGE</article>
<article id="contact">CONTACT</article>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I'm on 4.3.1, not 4.0.0  --sorry 4.1.3

Comment: @lesatdgl i update my answer with v4.3.1 - work like expected. I guess it is something else with your code..

Comment: Thanks, I'll crawl through the whole mess - it's weird to just see nothing happen.

Comment: If there's something more you need help with update your question. By the way -  Bootstrap got really good documentation (:

Comment: The problem here is updating a page from BS 3.x to 4.3 - it's a whole new deal and there's NO documentation - only comments from people saying "That's way to hard, I never do it" - I've decided to create new rather than update.

Comment: There is a part on docs of migration from v3x to 4 - but i agree with you. It's better to build again then trying to moderate old code. Good luck!

Comment: By the way i think you should mark this answer as correct and continue to code (:

Comment: Sorry, it's not correct. If you'd like to look at the complete code - which doesn't work - I'm happy to share

Comment: @lesatdgl OK.. Since this answer to your original question you can either edit your question with the relevant code and what is not working OR just open a new one..